# AngularFire2 infinite scrolling

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, infinite-scroll, angularfire2

I'm trying to implement an infinite scrolling with Ionic2 and Firebase.

I use AngularFire2. What I'd like to do is to add new items to the fetched list and not to reload the whole list.

```
let query$:Observable<any> = this.af.database.list(`quests/`, {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'date_published',
        limitToFirst: this.recentChunkLimit$ //Subject where I push new limit length
    }
}).publishReplay(1).refCount();
```

However, when I query list like that, the whole list is reloaded each time via websockets making each next update slower and slower.
Here is a screenshot of Network websockets tab:
[image: websockets]
And also I noticed that requests are made 2 times for each next chunk (though I put publishReplay). And it is happening in all apps where I used AngularFire2.
I might misunderstand something though. I definitely need some clarification.

//==========Edit============

Now, I somehow managed to implement what I want without reloading the whole list each time. Not the best implementation but it works. Basically, I created an observable array and load new values into it by subscribing to the next chunk observable (where I also get the last element to start with).
However the later problem still remains - in the sockets display I get data requested 2 times. [image]

Comment: what do you mean by the whole list? You requested 5 items. Then you requested for 10. The first 5 will be part of the 10 you requested. Isn't that your expectation?

Comment: I meant that the whole list is requested from the firebase, thus loading already loaded items once again. That's an expected behaviour but definitely not a desired one as for each higher limit, the loading time increases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using observables for `query` options just does not work like that. There is no facility in the underlying SDK to dynamically modify a query's `limitToFirst` and there's no way of doing it in AngularFire2.

Each time an observable `query` option emits a new value, a new Firebase ref is created. You can see it in the [source here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.7/src/database/firebase_list_factory.ts#L36-L93).

However, it would be possible to create an observable that represents an infinite list by doing something like this:

```ts
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import rxjs/add/observable/defer";
import rxjs/add/observable/zip";
import rxjs/add/operator/concatMap";
import rxjs/add/operator/filter";
import rxjs/add/operator/first";
import rxjs/add/operator/map";
import rxjs/add/operator/scan";
import rxjs/add/operator/share";
import rxjs/add/operator/startWith";

const pageSize = 100;
let notifier = new Subject<any>();
let last: Observable<any>;

let infiniteList = Observable

  // Use zip to combine the notifier's emissions with the last
  // child value:

  .zip(notifier, Observable.defer(() => last))

  // Use concatMap to emit a page of children into the
  // composed observable (note that first is used to complete
  // the inner list):

  .concatMap(([unused, last]) => this.af.database.list("quests", {
      query: {

        // If there is a last value, start at that value but ask
        // for one more:

        limitToFirst: last ? (pageSize + 1) : pageSize,
        orderByChild: "date_published",
        startAt: last
      }
    })
    .first()
  )

  // Use scan to accumulate the page into the infinite list:

  .scan((acc, list) => {

    // If this isn't the initial page, the page was started
    // at the last value, so remove it from the beginning of
    // the list:

    if (acc.length > 0) {
      list.shift();
    }
    return acc.concat(list);
  }, [])

  // Use share so that the last observable (see below) doesn't
  // result in a second subscription:

  .share();

// Each time a page is emitted, map to its last child value so
// that it can be fed back into the composed infinite list:

last = infiniteList
  .filter((list) => list.length > 0)
  .map((list) => list[list.length - 1].date_published)
  .startWith(null);

infiniteList.subscribe((list) => console.log(list));

// Each time the notifier emits, another page will be retrieved
// and added to the infinite list:

notifier.next();
notifier.next();
notifier.next();
```

That will work, but if the child upon which you are ordering has duplicate values, AngularFire2 won't be able to page through the results reliably until [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/362) is re-opened and resolved.

The resultant list is static. That is, children already paged in to the list won't be updated if the database changes. Implementing a dynamic list is more challenging, as duplicated and missing children can easily be effected by the limit-based paging mechanism.

---

Since writing this answer, I've made available tested implementations of forward and reverse, non-realtime and realtime infinite list observables in a library of Firebase observables that I have open sourced. See [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/cartant/firebase-thermite/tree/master/source/observable/database).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I solved it in a bit different fashion. Your solution is more pretty. And it's a good RxJS lesson. Could you also have a look at the second part of the question. I don't know if it is supposed to be this way;

Comment: By second part, do you mean the information appearing to be sent twice? I will have a quick look at it, tomorrow.

Comment: Regarding the WebSocket traffic showing the data being retrieved twice, you've found what I consider to be a bug. I'm talking with the AngularFire2 team about it.

Comment: FYI: the related [issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/819) and [PR](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/820).

Comment: One of the most-descriptive answers I've ever seen! Solved my problem and works great, thank you. This is actually an RxJS lesson!

Comment: There is one problem - It starts from the first firebase item, and I need to start it from the end. I changed `startAt` to `endAt` but the next page is not working correctly and shows thes same messages

Answer (score 2):

To add on to [cartant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42129729/6485996), if you wish to start at the end and retrieve list items in reverse, here is how you do it (I've added comments where code was changed).

```ts
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import rxjs/add/observable/defer";
import rxjs/add/observable/zip";
import rxjs/add/operator/concatMap";
import rxjs/add/operator/filter";
import rxjs/add/operator/first";
import rxjs/add/operator/map";
import rxjs/add/operator/scan";
import rxjs/add/operator/share";
import rxjs/add/operator/startWith";

const pageSize = 100;
let notifier = new Subject<any>();
let last: Observable<any>;

let infiniteList = Observable

  .zip(notifier, Observable.defer(() => last))

  .concatMap(([unused, last]) => this.af.database.list("quests", {
      query: {

        // Use limitToLast to move upward the list instead of downward

        limitToLast: last ? (pageSize + 1) : pageSize,
        orderByChild: "date_published",

        // Use endAt to start at the end of the list

        endAt: last
      }
    })
    .first()
  )

  .scan((acc, list) => {

    // Swap the roles of acc and list, as we want to 
    // concatenate from the beginning

    if (list.length > 0) {
      acc.shift();
    }
    return list.concat(acc);
  }, [])

  .share();



last = infiniteList
  .filter((list) => list.length > 0)

  // Use the first child in this list as the next endAt value

  .map((list) => list[0].date_published)

  // Use undefined instead of null, as endAt: null in angularfire2
  // will search for the last child that is null

  .startWith(undefined);

infiniteList.subscribe((list) => console.log(list));

notifier.next();
notifier.next();
notifier.next();
```